# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Stackexhcange is expanding the Winter Bash hat craziness that happened last year to the entire network.  During the time period 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013 whenever you do certain actions you will be rewarded at hat that your gravatar can wear. 
[image]
 Those that don't wish to participate can of course opt out.

It was stated that individual communities can voice whehter they want to participate or not.  We have until 28 November 2012 to voice whether we want to participate or not.  If we don't respond we will be considered to have opted out.

Comment: if my answer gets up to 15 then i'm going to send the ok.

Comment: that means we need three more upvote only

Comment: @ankit sharma i am so trying not to be sarcastic or a smart ass...  ;-)

Answer (score 20):

I say yes.  I don't see any reason not to participate, it'll be fun.

Comment: I'm in agreement, I think it'll be much fun

Comment: Putting hat on Avatar.Thats kinda cute.Sounds fun!

Comment: do we have to vote for this somewhere? i am totally in.

Comment: Up-voting/down-voting this question or answer will be counted as yes or no?

Comment: EITHER UPVOTE MY ANSWER OR UPVOTE THE QUESTION.

Comment: darn it capslock!

Comment: Are we in or not?

Comment: @AnkitSharma yup we're in, now to jsut send the confirmation in.  one of us mods will do it.

Comment: confirmation sent, we're opted in now.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't like the hat that much but i think we should participate. It will be fun.