# Do we want to join in the Winter Bash again?

Tags: discussion

Most of you probably remember [last year’s event](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/674/do-we-want-hats), but I’ll recap anyway, for the newbies among us. [Winter Bash](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/) is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can “wear”. We track everyone’s progress earning hats in a leaderboard.

I need to ask you all - should we do this again this year?

Comment: I honestly don't know what a downvote on this means.... please leave a comment or an alternative answer.

Comment: Maybe someone has just mistaken your question to be in favor of the *Winter Bash* (whereas your answer would be for that).

Comment: @ChristianRau - that is my interpretation too

Comment: i love the hats!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lets do ittttt

Comment: Decision made - I've sent the request to the SE gods.

Answer (score 6):

I certainly would want to do this again this year - it was a lot of fun.